# v-for Property or method is not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js, properties, undefined, v-for

I have a component called in another component witch use a v-for loop. But I can't get the property in the loop and don't understand why.

here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/playoutprod/octw411z/1/

Trouble append on this line (17) :

```
<td v-for="h in hs"/>{{h}}</td>
```

I tried this :

```
<td v-for="h in hs" :h="h"/>{{h}}</td>
```

witch render correctly with same error (but shows that "hs" array is well populated)

```
    <tr>
      <td h="date debut"></td>
      <td h="date fin"></td>
      <td h="formateur"></td>
      <td>En savoir +</td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code:

```
<td v-for="h in hs"/>{{h}}</td>
```

You are **closing** your `td` in `/>`.

So the code above is actually:

```
<td v-for="h in hs"></td>{{h}}</td>
```

Which is why you get `h` as undefined.

**Fix:** Don't close the `td`:

```
<td v-for="h in hs">{{h}}</td>
```

[**Updated JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/octw411z/3/).

Comment: Thanks ! I've been looking at vars problem, but not in the html code...

Comment: Humm.. What do you mean? Can you be more specific?